# validation error on patchEntity telling field is not unique

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I update an entity (so same id) and I get a validation error on a field which has a 'unique' rule.
I verified in the db that there is no an existing identical field and so I don't understand why I have this error as I update the record so obviously the field exists already because it's itself!
Is it a problem to have a 'unique' rule on patchEntity()?

```
[
    'site_name' => '...',
    'datas' => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

        'id' => (int) 653,
        'owner_id' => (int) 611,
        'extraemails' => [
        ],
        'owner' => object(App\Model\Entity\Owner) {

            'id' => (int) 611,
            'company' => 'This is the Company name',
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                'time' => '2015-06-06T18:07:17+0000',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                'time' => '2015-06-17T02:44:36+0000',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'email' => true,
                'phone' => true,
                'phone2' => true,
                'fax' => true,
                'company' => true,
                'tva_number' => true,
                'address' => true,
                'postcode' => true,
                'city' => true,
                'country_id' => true,
                'users' => true,
                'username' => true,
                'origin' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                'email' => true,
                'phone' => true,
                'postcode' => true,
                'city' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                'email' => '...',
                'phone' => '...',
                'postcode' => '...',
                'city' => '...'
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [
                'company' => [
                    'unique' => 'This company name exists already.'
                ]
            ],
            '[repository]' => 'Owners'

        },
....
```

**EDIT patchEntity() call added**

```
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($site->users[0], [

    'email' => $this->siteDatas['userEmail'],
    'phone' => $this->siteDatas['ownerPhone'],
    'role' => 'owner',
    'active' => 1,
    'extraemails' => $this->siteDatas['extraemails'],
    'owner' => [
        'company' => $this->siteDatas['ownerName'],
        'email' => $this->siteDatas['ownerEmail'],
        'phone' => $this->siteDatas['ownerPhone'],
        'address' => $this->siteDatas['ownerAddress'],
        'postcode' => $this->siteDatas['ownerPostcode'],
        'city' => $this->siteDatas['ownerCity'],
        'country_id' => $this->siteDatas['countryId'],
        'web' => $this->siteDatas['ownerWeb'],
        'origin' => 'sitra',
    ],
],
[
    'validate' => 'import',
    'associated' => [
        'Extraemails',
        'Owners' => [
            'validate' => 'import'
        ]
    ]
]);

if ($user->errors()) {

    // Here is where I get the 'unique' error
}
```

So again I verified that no other record in the table have the same 'company' name.
and as you can see in the debug() at the begining of my post, I have a owner->id and it's really the one I want to modify.

Here is the validator

```
public function validationImport(Validator $validator) {
    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('company')
        ->add('company', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table', 'message' => __("This company exists already.")])

        ...

            ])
        ;

    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: It is no problem to have a unique field on patchEntity(), are you sure you are not saving another record? could you show the code where you save and your validation rules?

Comment: @AlexStallen thanks for your comment, I've added the requestd infos.

Comment: You are saving a new entity, not a existing one

Comment: @AlexStallen surprising because I use patchEntity on an entity coming from a find() and user and owner have an id and [new] is false for both of them and here, only few fields are dirty, not all of them...

Comment: It is the only explanation, that it is trying to save as a new entity hence triggering the validation error, fair enough looking at the code I cante  see a problem, maybe put your whole edit function here?